# S3 ignores Content-Type for certain MIME types when using HTTP PUT

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-type, put

I'm using [HTTP PUT](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) to upload files to a bucket on S3. I've set up the correct permissions on the bucket and I can successfully upload files there. However, I'm having trouble setting the correct Content-Type. Here's the `curl` command I'm using:

```
$ echo 'TEST' |
    curl --data-binary @- -X PUT -L -H 'Content-Type: application/rss+xml' 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/test.xml'
```

`test.xml` is uploaded except when downloading it, I get `text/plain` as type. I've also verified that curl is indeed sending the right request. If I change the type to `application/rss+xmll` or `test/test`, I **correctly** get those back when downloading!

I'm out of ideas. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: When downloading it... where?  In a browser? Or with `curl -v`?  The browser could be mangling it... Similar issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=104358